# Inheritance of C# attribute classes

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, custom-attributes

How does inheritance of attribute classes work in C#? To clarify, I am talking about the inheritance of the attribute classes themselves (i.e. base classes of `System.Attributes`), NOT any classes that happen to have them as attribute.

For some reason, I cannot seem to find anything on this (my searches always turn up with the other meaning).

For example, if a have a class `AttributeA` which extends `System.Attribute`:

1. Do I have to separately mark subclasses of `AttributeA` with `[AttributeUsage()]`. (Since `System.AttributeUsage`'s inheritance is `true`, I don't think I will.)
2. Will `AllowMultiple=false` on the `AttributeUsage` of `AttributeA` prevent me from having multiple *subclasses* of `AttributeA` for attributes?

EDIT:

Programmers can only read code.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple=false)]
class AttributeA
{ }

class AttributeB : AttributeA
{ }

class AttributeC : AttributeA
{ }

[AttributeB]
[AttributeC]
class Foo
{ }
```

Does this work?

Comment: It seems to me that both of these could be checked by trying it...

Comment: Yes, I am not able to do that right now...and I wanted to save someone else some time on this too. Even I could just *find* the relevant documentation, I would be happy...

Comment: Your basic assumption should be that there is no magic.

Answer (score 1):

(I was finally able to try it.)

The example code does compile. I still like to have documentation, although I suppose C# is C# and it isn't going to change that. (Right?)

Evidently:

1. The subclasses inherit `AttributeUsage`, as expected.
2. `AllowMultiple` refers *only* to attributes of (strictly) the original class, not subclasses.
3. Also, `AttributeUsage` can be effectively "re-defined".

With

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
class AttributeA : Attribute
{ }

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = true)]
class AttributeB : AttributeA
{ }

class AttributeC : AttributeA
{ }
```

the following is okay

```
[AttributeA]
[AttributeB]
[AttributeB]
[AttributeC]
class Foo
{ }
```

but this isn't

```
[AttributeA]
[AttributeB]
[AttributeC]
[AttributeC]
class Foo
{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control this behavior by using the named parameter Inherited for your AttributeUsageAttribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
class AttributeA
{ }

class AttributeB : AttributeA
{ }

class AttributeC : AttributeA
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute usage is for the classes using the attributes.

For example, if you mark class A with AttributeA and class B is a subclass of A, you don't need to mark class B with AttributeB if AttributeA AttributeUsage's inheritance is true.

Comment: You miss the question. I am asking about marking `A` with `AttributeA` AND subclass `AttributeB`.

Comment: [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited=true)] 
public sealed class AttributeUsageAttribute : Attribute. So it looks like it is inheritable.

Comment: And it that allowed if `AllowMultiple=false`?

Comment: If it is inheritable it should inherit everything